# Не отображается анимация keyframes. Работает только в Хроме

Tags: css, sass, keyframes

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
 0%, 100% {
  background-image: url("../img/bg1.jpg"); }
 33% {
  background-image: url("../img/bg2.jpg"); }
 66% {
  background-image: url("../img/bg3.jpg"); } }
@-moz-keyframes slide {
 0%, 100% {
  background-image: url("../img/bg1.jpg"); }
 33% {
  background-image: url("../img/bg2.jpg"); }
 66% {
  background-image: url("../img/bg3.jpg"); } }
@-o-keyframes slide {
 0%, 100% {
  background-image: url("../img/bg1.jpg"); }
 33% {
  background-image: url("../img/bg2.jpg"); }
 66% {
  background-image: url("../img/bg3.jpg"); } }
@keyframes slide {
 0%, 100% {
  background-image: url("../img/bg1.jpg"); }
 33% {
  background-image: url("../img/bg2.jpg"); }
 66% {
  background-image: url("../img/bg3.jpg"); } }
@media -sass-debug-info{filename{font-         family:file\:\/\/D\:\/Projects\/Work\/Vegetables2\/css\/sass\/main\.sass}line{font-family:\0000333}}
.banner {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); }
@media -sass-debug-info{filename{font-   family:file\:\/\/D\:\/Projects\/Work\/Vegetables2\/css\/sass\/main\.sass}line{font-family:\0000340}}
.banner:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(118, 144, 164, 0.4);
  z-index: 0; }

@media -sass-debug-info{filename{font-family:file\:\/\/D\:\/Projects\/Work\/Vegetables2\/css\/sass\/main\.sass}line{font-family:\0000349}}
.v-center {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  padding: 0 5%; }

@media -sass-debug-info{filename{font-family:file\:\/\/D\:\/Projects\/Work\/Vegetables2\/css\/sass\/main\.sass}line{font-family:\0000355}}
.banner-bg {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #222;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: slide ease-in-out 30s both infinite;
  -webkit-animation: slide ease-in-out 30s both infinite inline-block;
  -moz-animation: slide ease-in-out 30s both infinite inline-block;
  -o-animation: slide ease-in-out 30s both infinite inline-block; }

  /*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

Answer (score 1):

Анимации по-разному назовите и заработает, например slide1 для хром, slide2 для оперы и тд

Comment: К сожалению,не помогло

Comment: Только сейчас заметил, что это у вас там за inline-block в самом конце свойства?